# accessing array outside the parent for loop in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, split

i have this code snippet in my java application. i need to access the rule_body_arr_l2 outside the parent for loop. i tried to initialize the array outside the for loop but in the last line when i want to display its value, it says the array might not have been initialized yet.

```
String rule_body="person(?x),patientid(?y),haspid(?x,?y)";
     System.out.println(rule_body);
     String rule_body_arr[]=rule_body.split("\\),");
     String rule_body_arr_l2[];
     for(int x=0;x<rule_body_arr.length;x++)
    {
        System.out.println(rule_body_arr[x]);            
        rule_body_arr_l2=rule_body_arr[x].split("\\(");
        System.out.println("LEVEL TWO SPLIT");
        for(int y=0;y<rule_body_arr_l2.length;y++)
        {

            System.out.println(rule_body_arr_l2[y]);

        }

    }
     for(int x=0;x<6;x++)
     {
         System.out.println(rule_body_arr_l2[x]);
     }
```

Guidance is required in the matter

Comment: Just as a note, in Java, while both versions of the syntax are allowed, the convention is to put the array marker on the *type* rather than the variable name.  So `String[] foo ...` rather than `String foo[] ...`

Comment: @IanMcLaird thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try splitting at ), u wont get the comma problem

Answer (score 1):

If so then initialize `rule_body_arr_l2` like

```
String[] rule_body_arr_l2 = new String[YOUR_POSSIBLE_LENGTH];
```

If you are not sure the `length` of String in prior declaration then better using `ArrayList<String>` like

```
ArrayList<String> rule_body_arr_l2= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: the length is unknow as the string above will come from DB and can be of variable length. should i use arraylist instead?

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan Then use List<String> as I suggested in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you must specify the array size. You haven't created an array. What you have done is, you have only created an *array reference*.

By default, in Java all references are set to null when initializing.

You must instantiate an array by giving an exact size for it.

For example,

`int[] numberArray = new int[5];`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, rather than using a `split` to parse the `String` you could use a *regular expression* with a `Pattern` to *parse* your `String` with something like

```
String rule_body = "person(?x),patientid(?y),haspid(?x,?y)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("person\\((.+)\\),patientid\\((.+)\\),haspid\\((.+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(rule_body);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.printf("person = %s%n", m.group(1));
    System.out.printf("patientid = %s%n", m.group(2));
    System.out.printf("haspid = %s%n", m.group(3));
}
```

Which outputs

```
person = ?x
patientid = ?y
haspid = ?x,?y
```

Comment: i am doing exactly this but i also have one other string in the form of person(alan),patientid(01),haspid(Alan,01). i need to find if the two are same except values in the brackets i.e (?x,?y, alan, 01) then replace ?x with alan and patientid with 01 and so for remaining. in light of ur answer can u suggest me that ur method is better or the split will work with it.

Comment: Check if `m.matches()`, if so; use your second `String` (they match).